# after trying to configure my aws cli, nothing is written in the crendentials and config files

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

When configuring my AWS CLI, I have a problem with my config and credentials files.
Even after entering my access key and my secret access key, when i try to type the following command:

[image]

i get permission denied as you can see.
I changed the file permission with chmod and here is what i got.
[image]

Comment: `~/.aws/credentials` is not an executable file.

Answer (score 1):

`~/.aws/credentials` is a file. You have to open it with any of the editors like `vi` or `vim`, `nano`.

For ex:

```
vi ~/.aws/credentials
```

To configure the credentials for aws cli, you can directly use the command

```
aws configure
```

Comment: i used aws configure. I entered my access key and my secret access key and my region and the output type.
I followed these steps step by step.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html
Still i don't get an empty configuration files.

Comment: After doing these steps, do you still have an empty `~/.aws/credentials` file?

Comment: you executed `aws configure` as which user?